# Where can I find/download infos about Special Use Airpsace (SUA) around the world?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, special-use-airspace

I would like to know if there are any websites where I can find information (and possibly download it) about Special Use Airpsace (SUAs) around the world in terms of time validity, geographical coordinates, flight level restrictions... 
If am not mistaking, [aixm.areo](http://www.aixm.aero/) is a website where I can find such information regarding the European region; I would like to know if there are other websites that allow to download such infos for the rest of the world (North America, South America, Africa, Asia, Oceania....)

If you know please could you also provide some links?

Note: the following quantities should be contained:

- time validity
- geographical coordinates (lat/lon)
- flight level restrictions

Comment: Ok I will reformulate the question; thanks for the comment!!

Comment: See airspace at each AIS, e.g. for France, the [lower airspace](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2016-10-13/html/eAIP/FR-ENR-6.1-fr-FR.html#ENR-6.1-1) map at [AIS France](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2016-10-13/html/index-fr-FR.html). (Upper space is [here](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2016-10-13/html/eAIP/FR-ENR-6.2-fr-FR.html#ENR-6.2)). Here is the [RTBA](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dossier/3rdparty/CARTE_RTBA_0116.pdf) map (military, low altitude)

Answer (score 1):

- EU: [aixm.aero](http://www.aixm.aero/)

  - France: [sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2016-10-13/html/index-fr-FR.html)

    - [Upper space](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/aip/enligne/FRANCE/AIRAC-2016-10-13/html/eAIP/FR-ENR-6.2-fr-FR.html#ENR-6.2)
    - [RTBA map](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dossier/3rdparty/CARTE_RTBA_0116.pdf) (military, low altitude)
- USA: [sua.faa.gov](https://sua.faa.gov/)

  - AIXM Data: [nfdc.faa.gov](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56DaySub-2015-06-25)

---

- Diverse locations: [soaringweb.org](http://soaringweb.org/Airspace/)

---

<sup>This is a community wiki, just add to it.</sup>

Comment: the link to sua.faa.gov is almost what I am looking for, but I would like to get also the geographical coordinates of the polygon defining the surface of a special use area... do you have other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look this up in the Aeronautical Information Publication (AIP) for each individual country. Special Use Airspaces are contained in section ENR 5 of an AIP. Many AIP's are available online. You can find a comprehensive list here: https://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/ais-online

Simply select a country, open their AIP, and navigate to the ENR 5 section.

Below is an excerpt from AIP Denmark ENR 5.1 as an example.

[image]

Be aware that far from all SUA's have fixed activation times. Some SUA's do have published activation times in the AIP, but for many others you will have to check NOTAM's to determine whether or not they are active.